# NHibernate only eagerly loads Dictionary <map> when stepping through code

Tags: c#, debugging, nhibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a class `Unit` with a `Dictionary` of `Parts`. The mapping looks like this

```
<class name="Unit" table="Units">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="CreationDate" />

<property name="MacAddress" />
<property name="OEMId" />
<property name="SerialNumber" />
<property name="QualityControlState" />

<map name="Parts" table="UnitParts" lazy="false">
  <key column="UnitId"/>
  <index column="TypeOfPart" type="integer"/>
  <composite-element class="UnitPart">
    <property name="PartInfo"/>
    <property name="Remarks"/>
  </composite-element>
</map>
```

When I `Session.SaveOrUpdate(Unit)` all goes well: the two tables are filled with the right data. And the unit is retreivable (with all its `Parts`) using `Session.Get(typeof(Unit)` as well.

**The problem: Obtaining multiple units lazy loads the `Parts` `Dictionary`.**

The problem rephrased in pseudo code: `LoadMethodOfPartsDictionary = (Stepping with Debugger) ? Eagerly : Lazy;`

The following code baffles me. When I step through it using the debugger the `Parts` `Dictionary` of a `Unit` is eagerly loaded. But when I run to `return Units` (not stepping through `Units = crit.Future<Unit>().ToList<Unit>();`) its seems NHibernate wants to lazy load as the `Parts` `Dictionary` suddenly is `NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericMap`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Retreives a list of units by a set of criteria.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A list of units that fall within/match the criteria</returns>
public static List<Unit> GetUnits(List<KeyValuePair<Unit.SortableProperties, ListSortDirection>> SortColumnOrder, out uint NumberOfRecordsWithoutLimit, uint Start = 0, int End = -1, FilterUnits Filter = default(FilterUnits))
{
    List<Unit> Units = default(List<Unit>);

    NumberOfRecordsWithoutLimit = 0;
    using (ISession Session = ORM.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria<Unit>();

            //Limit result set, used for paging
            if (End > 0)
            {
                crit.SetFirstResult((int)Start);
                crit.SetMaxResults(End);
            }

            //TODO: Implement filter code here

            //Add the sort order
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Unit.SortableProperties, ListSortDirection> kvp in SortColumnOrder)
            {
                String PropertyName = "";
                switch (kvp.Key)
                {
                    case Unit.SortableProperties.PRODUCTIONDATE:
                        PropertyName = "CreationDate";
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException(kvp.Key.ToString() + " isn't implemented for sorting yet.");
                }
                crit.AddOrder(new Order(PropertyName, (kvp.Value == ListSortDirection.Ascending)));
            }

            if (End > 0)
            {
                //Count the total units available in database.
                Units = crit.Future<Unit>().ToList<Unit>(); //This seems to lazy load the Units
                IFutureValue<int> RowCount = Session.CreateCriteria<Unit>()
                                        .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
                                        .FutureValue<int>();
                NumberOfRecordsWithoutLimit = (uint)RowCount.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Units = (List<Unit>)crit.List<Unit>();
                NumberOfRecordsWithoutLimit = (uint)Units.Count;
            }

            Transaction.Commit();
            Session.Close();
            return Units;
        }
    }
}
```

Any hints are appreciated.

P.S. I used the [Debugging] tag as this seems to be key in this scenario.

Comment: I guess with stepping through code works because the `Session` isn't closed yet. But in the mapping I have set `lazy` to `false`. And `Session.Get<Unit>(Id);` seems to work alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different concepts how to recieve the data from the DB. In case of one-to-many (lists, dictionaries).

1) We can call NHibernate to get data by ID or reference (similar cases)

```
session.Get<Unit>(1);
```

In this case NHibernates injects all the properties **not** marked as *lazy*. So in your case, this will cause to eagerly load of the Parts as well.

the similar is the reference property: `public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }` of ane `OtherObject`

```
var otherObject = ... // get from session
var unit = otherObject.Unit; // the full Unit with all `Lazy="false"` properties is loaded
```

2) But we can also use the `Criteria` (As in your case). However, this is different approach. In this case, we are explicitly saying that we want only work with `Unit`

```
Units = crit.Future<Unit>().ToList<Unit>();
```

This has many advantages:

- we can do efficient paging only on the `Unit` table
- only the Unit is loaded (maybe the Parts won't be used)
- if Parts are used, they will be lazily loaded

But if really needed *(regardles of side effects like inocrrect paging)* we can also load the Parts in one select:

```
Units = crit
  .SetFetchMode("Parts", FetchMode.Eager)
  .Future<Unit>()
  .ToList<Unit>();
```

Now is all populated at once.

3) The approach I would vote for (I am using 100%) is to let collection to be lazy, and assign the `batch-size` [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

EXTENDED

To show you how to change the mapping:

```
<map name="Parts" table="UnitParts" lazy="true" batch-size="25">
```

From that moment, your Util is lightweight. No Parts loaded, until really needed. If the session is opened during the whole request, once the Parts are touched, they will be loaded in one SELECT (if the page size of Utils is not larger then 25)

This approach is very efficient, becuase it uses the power of ORM - everything is lazy

Comment: Ok, so its by design. Thats good to know. NHibernate can be a bit overwhelming sometimes. I am only using it since a couple of weeks. I have tried setting the fetch mode. I will try it out right now and see if it works. The units are indeed loaded in pages. And a unit can be selected to work with, managing its parts. But I could of course then only load the parts, which uses less data transport. I'll try the `SetFetchMode`. I am building a distributed application and for as far as I have read, out of the box lazy loading of NHibernate isn't going to work.

Comment: The `SetFetchMode` will be a big helper for you. Because, you can leave the collection lazy for any other cases, while in the specific Criteria, you can load that all. But be aware, that in that case paging won't work. I would strongly suggest to use the batch-size setting on the `map` mapping (e.g. 25). That will mean, that if you are going to take 20 Units, only one separated select for all their parts will be executed in addition. BUT your paging will be working

Comment: What do you mean "in that case paging won't work". With paging I mean http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html or should I use the term `pagination` instead? But batch/page size may change in C# code by the user. Like show 25/50/100 records per page.

Comment: I have the following code now `Units = crit.SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(10).SetFetchMode("Parts", FetchMode.Eager).Future<Unit>().ToList<Unit>();` and it returns me 10 units of the same persistent object. But there are three Units in database. So pagination wont work like this? Without the `Set[First/Max]Results` I get 42 units, which equals 3 x `Unit` x 14 `Parts` per unit.

Comment: So I am encountering this now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product ? Maybe its faster to query twice, one query to obtain the `Unit`s with eagerly loaded `Parts` and one for obtaining the total number of `Unit`s available in database...

Comment: You got the point! the Cartesion product is the evil. But! with the batch-size you would have: 1) pagination on top of the Utils and 2) NEXT select for downloading all realted Parts. So, this is what you want. Util will be lightweight (lazy = false for Parts). you won't use SetFetch. No. But, while session is still open, you will get the Parts loaded, once firstly accessed ...

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I am on my way again.

Comment: Great. NHibernate is amazing tool. But sometimes we do suffer, when we learn it. good luck with NHibernate ;)